# How can I deploy my StackBlitz website and fix the error or stuck loading issue on a new tab?

Tags: firebase, github, static, stackblitz

How do I deploy this website?

I created a website on **StackBlitz**. The preview runs fine, but when I open in a new tab I get an error or the blue loading bar appears on the website and never finishes loading.

The website itself is pretty simple, just **HTML** and **CSS**. I linked it to **Github** and all that as well. Assuming the problem happens while deploying, how do I fix that?

I don't have an account that works with **Firebase** in any manner. If that isn't the problem, then what can it be?

I tried connecting Firebase, Github, and making changes to the code. I was expecting for it to load the same as the preview.